# How to know if two power series solutions are linearly independent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm currently studying power series to solve differential equations. I would like to know if there's a way to tell whether two solutions are linearly independent or not. I think evaluating the Wronskian would be a tough task because the series may not be expressed in $\sum$ notation.

For instance if I'm working on a power series centered at a regular singular point, Frobenius theorem provides me a solution $y_1(x)$. If I were to find another one in the form

$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int\frac{e^{-\int P(x)\,dx}}{y_1^2(x)}\,dx$$
I know that this solution is independent because I created it to be independent. However if I solve the system and find "two" solutions, how do I know if these solutions are  linearly independent?  I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: You're looking for the [Wronksian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Comment: @sid I said it might be very tough to evaluate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** After clarifying in chat, it seems there are *two* questions here regarding finding power series solutions to second order, linear ODE.

> 1. Will the two solutions I get always be linearly independent?
> 2. After I've found two solutions, how can I check whether or not they are linearly independent?

**Answer to Question 1:**

When using the [Method of Frobenius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) to obtain a power series solution of a second order linear ODE in the neighborhood of a regular singular point, in *can* happen that you end up finding only *one* linearly independent power series solution. (You do find two solutions, but the second is a constant multiple of the first.)

This happens when solving Bessel's equation
$$
x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+(x^2-\mu^2)y(x)=0
$$
about $x=0$. It is a long and tedious calculation, too long to type out, but you can study it [here in Example 5.7.2 starting on page 345](http://books.google.com/books?id=qVtoAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA345#v=onepage&q=solve%20the%20bessel%20equation&f=false).

However, you *can* always fall back on the method you alluded to above, often called [reduction of order/variation of constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order), to find a second linearly independent solution $y_2$ once you have any one solution $y_1$. That applies the Bessel's equation as well.

**Answer to Question 2:**

Typically we would compute the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of $y_1$ and $y_2$, $W(y_1(x),y_2(x))(x)$ and appeal to the fact that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent iff the Wronskian in nonzero. When $y_1$ and $y_2$ are *power series* this looks to be a cumbersome calculation. However, let's appeal to the full power of the Wronskian statement regarding linear independence:

> If $W(y_1,y_2)(x_0)\not=0$ for some $x_0\in I$, then $y_1(x)$ and
>   $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent on $I$.

Case 1: Ordinary points

Now just pick $x_0$ judiciously: say, $x_0$ is the ordinary point about which we found the two series solutions
$$
y_1(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n, \quad y_2(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x-x_0)^n, 
$$
Then 
$$
W(y_1,y_2)(x_0)=y_1(x_0)y_2'(x_0)-y_2(x_0)y_1'(x_0)=a_0b_1-b_0a_1
$$
tells the tale (whether this is zero or not).

Case 2: (Regular) singular points

This takes quite a bit of typing. I will punt by pointing you [here](http://howellkb.uah.edu/MAPH/Notes/Series/Frob.pdf), page 14. If someone has a better "preserved" source than this and/or wants to edit my answer to give the full details in this case, please do.

Comment: the second one.

Comment: If the second, then why bother with the reduction of order/variation of constants part you mentioned?

Comment: Hmmm I thought that you could apply the Method of Frobenius and sometimes obtain _only_ one solution. Do I always get $2$?

Comment: Yes, just one. What I meant above, is that if you look at the work for Bessel's equation you end up doing Frobenius two separate times. But you are correct, an application of Frobenius produces one solution.

Comment: OK it looks like I have answered a question that you didn't ask! But, I honestly do think that it might be helpful to someone else viewing the site. Would you consider either posting the second question as a separate question and I can post this answer there (and delete it here)? Or, you could edit this question to contain both items and my answer here would only address one of them. I'm just thinking it might be educational for someone else. (I think both are nice questions!)

Comment: To be clear, one might get two solutions from Frobenius, but they're mostly linearly dependent. right? Also, I'd have to identify my differential equation as a Bessel equation to get the solutions $J_\mu$, $Y_\mu$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19134/discussion-between-johnd-and-notstrang).

Comment: @JohnD The resource you pointed out in the last seems incorrect when it mentions that for roots of the indicial equation differing by a positive integer, the solution *must* include the logarithmic term too, which I’m pretty sure may be not there.